# Upload images via post and horizontal progress dialog

Tags: android, file-upload, image-uploading, android-progressbar, android-volley

I want to upload multiple images and json via post method. I do not want to use `BASE 64` method because it is 37% more heavy then image upload via file upload.

I am use below code for upload.

```
public void doFileUpload(ArrayList<UploadImage> images){
        try {
            MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(link);
            //MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
            for(UploadImage img : images){
                FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(img.getImageFile());

                entityBuilder.addPart("uploaded_file", bin1);
            }
            post.setEntity(entityBuilder.build());
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

            final String response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

            Log.e("Response", response_str);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I also want to show horizontal progress dialog with progress how many images are upload. I have do R & D for this and find [this link.](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/android-image-upload-activity/)  But here is not any way to upload multiple images and also show `horizontal progress dialog` with progress.

I am use `volley library` to upload images with json.

Is there any other best way to upload multiple images to server?

Thanks

Comment: Volley doesn't offer upload feature, of course you can override `Request`'s getPostBody() method to submit some bytes data, but each request won't callback with requesting progress.

Comment: Ok Thanks @VinceStyling I have got with another logic like I will send on extra parameter in json that how many images I will send and then add images with 'uploadimage[i]' i is integer with 1,2,3 etc